# How can I detect Rectangles and Boxes in PDF using C# iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a sample of PDF that looks like this

[image]

I am trying to retrieve those Rectangles/Boxes using C# iTextSharp

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++i)
        {
            strPageNumber = i.ToString();
            if (intCommentCount >= 5)
            {
                break;
            }

            PdfDictionary pagedic = reader.GetPageN(i);

            var thing = reader.GetPageContent(i);
            string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(thing, 0, thing.Length);
            PdfArray rectarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.RECT));

            if (rectarray == null || rectarray.Size == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
         }
```

However, unfortunately, the rectarray comes back as null. I tried BOX instead of RECT, but rectarray also comes back as null

What is the way to collect BOX/RECTANGLE objects from the PDF using C# iTextSharp

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please first tell us what those rectangles actually are? They may be bitmap or vector graphics in page / pattern / Xobject content streams, or they may be annotations, or something else. Collecting the boxes is different for all those cases. If you are not sure, please share the PDF in question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PdfPig](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig) to retrieve these rectangles.
I don't know if the rectangles are `Path` or `Annotations`, so here is the code for both cases:

```cs
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open("file.pdf"))
{      
    for (int i = 0; i < document.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var page = document.GetPage(i + 1);

        // if the rectangle are paths
        var paths = page.ExperimentalAccess.Paths;

        // if the rectangle are annotations
        var annotations = page.ExperimentalAccess.GetAnnotations().ToList();
        foreach (var annotation in annotations)
        {
            var rectangle = annotation.Rectangle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question clearly asks for a solution ***using C# iTextSharp***. An answer for a different library, therefore, is not what the OP seems to want.